# How to choose a package name for a kivy/python apk?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am a final semester student of B.Tech and as my final semester project i have opt to make an android application using python.I have build the code successfully & now I am trying to generate an apk file of android application. I have built the android application with help of kivy & python. I am trying this site http://android.kivy.org/ If someone knows how to use this site then please tell what should i enter in package name field...I have tried a lot package name...like...org.kivy.server,org.kivy.fullserver,org.kivy.server.modified,org.test.client,org.test.myapp,org.test.myclient...and many more...but none of the package name works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if android.kivy.org is working right now, it's not used by very many people.

Mostly we build our own apks locally, with the instructions at http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html .

Comment: Sorry for this silly comment but will it be possible that i will send the whole code of application & u can mail me the apk of that...I hve tried many things but i am not able to generate the apk...